# AngularJS breaks when minified while using a service

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, uglifyjs

Ok, I'm fairly new to AngularJS, so please don't laugh if this is easy. I'm attempting to follow [Todd Motto's Opinionated AngularJS Styleguide for Teams](https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide). I know it doesn't look much like it since I tried to reduce the code. I'm using Grunt to uglify my code. If I turn mangling off, it works. Otherwise, I get the error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: aProvider <- a
```

I know this is because the name is getting mangled, so it doesn't know what to map it to, but I have no idea how/where to inject the correct name. I've tried to track it down. I think it is when we try to resolve the route, and the DataService is being injected, and because there is no inject for our DataService, I think it gets mangled.

I've tried to reduce my code down as much as possible. This also relies on angular and angular-route, as well as a file called data.json (which could be anything, it doesn't really matter). Then just run `grunt debug`.

Please let me know if I missed anything and thank-you for your time.

### File Structure

```
├── data.json
├── gruntfile.js
├── index.html
└── js
    ├── app
    │   └── app.js
    └── vendor
        ├── angular-route.js
        └── angular.js
```

### gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        uglify: {
            debugMine: {
                options: {
                    wrap: true,
                    sourceMap: true,
                    mangle: false,
                },
                files: { 'js/production.min.js': [
                    'js/app/app.js',
                ]}
            },
            debugVendor: {
                files: { 'js/vendor.min.js': [
                    'js/vendor/angular.js',
                    'js/vendor/angular-route.js',
                ]}
            }
        },
        connect: {
            server: {
                options: {
                    port: 8000,
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            myscripts: {
                files: ['js/app/**'],
                tasks: ['uglify:debugMine'],
            },
            options: {
                livereload: true,
                spawn: false
            },
            vendorscripts: {
                files: ['js/vendor/**'],
                tasks: ['uglify:debugVendor'],
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    grunt.registerTask('debug',
                        'Create a debug build of the code',
                        [
                            'uglify:debugMine',
                            'uglify:debugVendor',
                            'connect:server',
                            'watch',
                        ]);
};
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Mangled Names Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h2>I'm above the content</h2>
        <hr>
        <!-- Begin Content -->
        <div ng-view></div>
        <!-- End Content -->
        <hr>
        <h2>I'm below the content</h2>

        <!-- Begin Release Scripts -->
        <script src='js/vendor.min.js'></script>
        <script src='js/production.min.js'></script>
        <!-- End Release Scripts -->
    </body>
</html>
```

### app.js

```
console.log('Define functions that make up app');

function DataService($http) {
    console.log('Setting up data service');
    var DataService = {};

    DataService.getData = function() {
        console.log('In DataService.getData, getting data');
        return $http.get('/data.json');
    };

    return DataService;
}

function DocumentCtrl(data) {
    console.log('In DocumentCtrl, check data');
    var self = this;
    self.data = data;
}

DocumentCtrl.resolve = {
    data: function(DataService) {
        console.log('Call DataService.getData()');
        return DataService.getData();
    },
}

function RouteConfig($routeProvider) {
    console.log('Define routes');
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            template: "<h4>I'm in the content and above the data</h4><hr>{{docCtrl.data}}<hr><h4>I'm in the content and below the data</h4>",
            controllerAs: 'docCtrl',
            controller: 'DocumentCtrl',
            resolve: {
                data: function(DataService) {
                    console.log('Call DataService.getData()');
                    return DataService.getData();
                },
            }
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' })
}

console.log('Define module');

angular
    .module('app', ['ngRoute'])
    .factory('DataService', ['$http', DataService])
    .controller('DocumentCtrl', ['data', DocumentCtrl])
    .config(['$routeProvider', RouteConfig]);
```

Comment: try this in controller .controller('DocumentCtrl', ['DataService', DocumentCtrl])

Answer (score 2):

Adding `mangle:false` to `uglify.debugVendor.options` will probably fix it. If not then you probably need to compile vendor and your files together so uglify can use them in the same scope.

```
    uglify: {
        // ...
        debugVendor: {
            options: {
                mangle: false,
            },
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your service name is `DataService` therefore the declaration in your configuration should be with the same name like:

```
.controller('DocumentCtrl', ['DataService', DocumentCtrl])
```

From your sample above:

```
angular
    .module('app', ['ngRoute'])
    .factory('DataService', ['$http', DataService])
    .controller('DocumentCtrl', ['DataService', DocumentCtrl])
    .config(['$routeProvider', RouteConfig]);
```

Comment: Yup agree with this, OP see a note on minification here https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05 alternatively use ng-annotate grunt task to do this for you.

Comment: In that style guide I linked, he talks about using resolve to get data before calling the controller, instead of getting data in the controller: https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide#routing-resolves I want it to resolve before I call the controller. And besides, even if I add the 'DataService' to my controller definition, it still breaks with mangling.

Answer (score 0):

uglify change angularjs service name into a,b, .. . So you have to change uglify options:

```
options: {
    mangle: false,
},
```